# Rider 2021.3.3 doesn't resolve all of my typescript references properly

Tags: angular, typescript, package.json, rider

Lately JetBrains Rider seems to have a problem resolving most references in my Angular 12.0.5 project.
E.g. none of the angular pipes can be resolved anymore:

[image]

But also some rxjs references have weird warnings:

[image]

I can't pin-point it for sure but I have the feeling it started after updating to Rider 2021.3.3.
Weirdly enough we have a second project that runs on Angular 12.1.0 where all references can be resolved. Although, I somehow doubt it has something to do with versioning.

I already tried clearing all Rider caches (File > Invalidate Caches).

I'd be greatful for some ideas on how to resolve the issue!

Comment: I tried downgrading to 2021.2.3 but had the same issue.

Comment: A colleague had success by deleting node_modules and then letting Rider run the npm i but that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution my colleague suggested worked in the end but it seems crucial to actually delete the "node_modules" folder rather than deleting its contents.
So the final solution looks like this:

1. Exit Rider
2. Delete the complete node_modules folder rather than its contents
3. Start Rider
4. Wait for all indexing to finish
5. Wait for the automatic popup from Rider that suggests you should run "npm i".

If you don't see the popup in Step 5. you can always start a console inside of rider and enter "npm install" there. You should see that the command is highlighted by rider like so:

[image]

Then you can press "CTRL + ENTER" to run the command in riders context.

Comment: Worked perfect! Angular 15,  Rider 2022.3.2

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if `Rider` has not indexed your angular project files.
Right click on the root directory of your angular project and under `Tools` menu, click on `Start index`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the angular project folder in Rider from the root so you can see `node_modules` folder in the `Explorer`. The syntax errors happen if the folder is opened from a descendant folder like `src`.